# My Account Lost Administrator permission

Tags: admin, permissions

Need help to solve this problem.

First i did reflush all upgrade that didn’t complete that cause
"WordPress Error: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"
with force upgrade:
http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/28/wordpress-error-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page/

it works, but the next problem is
my account lost the administrator permissions. 
(such like add plugins, add widget, add menu, etc)

i tried to:
- Manually Add a WordPress Administrator to the Database (Using MyPHPAdmin a:1:{s:13:”administrator”;b:1;})
and it does not work
- refresh the account password, also not work.

and now it does really nightmare for me.. try and look over google with no solution.
any solution for this?

thanks

Comment: Do the following and revert back with the results,

1. Disable all plugins by renaming the folders using CPanel file manager or FTP.

2. Activate the 2012 or 2013 WP default theme.

Comment: doesnot work, the account still have no administrator role, it's not about the theme issue, it's database issue.. somehow the user permission got flushed even i set a:1:{s:13:”administrator”;b:1;} with meta lvl 10

Answer (score -1):

I Resolve this.. 
looks like the force upgrade change the option_value of wp_user_role under wp_option.
so i replace it with the fresh value..

thank you